# Create const.js on Meteor

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

I would like create const.js in `/imports/startup/client/const.js`. My content :

```
export const $body = document.body || document.documentElement;
export const $header = document.getElementById('js-header');
...
```

So, when i import my const in my `/imports/ui/components/header.js` :

```
import { $header } from '../../startup/client/const';
```

I've a error `'$header is undefined'`

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is your code running before the document is ready/the `js-header` element exists?

Comment: Good remark. My js-header is include on my layout. So i think no, he'snt exist. But I do not see how to solve the prob ?

Comment: Perhaps refactor `$header` to be a function that returns the element, rather than just a static value? So like: `() => document.getElementById('js-header')`, and use it like: `$header()`. That way it would look for the element when it was needed, rather than at startup. I don't know if that's the best solution for your needs, but it's one possibility.

Comment: Oh yes, i will try this methode :) I think it's good idea for my case. Thank you Joe !

Comment: Glad I could help :)